# Remove curent rows from Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to remove all the rows from a DataTable in JS. When the user presses a button it should delete the previous table information and only display the correct table. I have the ajax call in a button click function and it creates the table properly but it never removes any of the previous data. I've tried doing `fnClearData()`, and setting where I append the data to HTML instead of `appendTo` but with no success.

I create the table with

```
<div>
    <table id="database" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="display: none;">
        <thead><tr><th>Casename</th><th>Password</th><th>Hash</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then I add to the table by doing

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/getSpecificPass",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(val.casename),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(response) {
        //response =response.result;
        $.each(response.result,function(key,val){
            var html="<tr>";
            html+="<td>"+localStorage.getItem('case_name')+"</td><td>"+val.password+"</td><td>"+val.hash+"</td>"
            html+="</tr>"
            $(html).appendTo($("#database tbody"));
        });
                                                  
      $('#database').dataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just managed to figure it out. For anyone else running into this issue,

When my button is pressed I created an if statement to check if the table contains data and if so, delete the table and then re-create the blank table

```
if ($('#database tbody') != ""){
    $('#database').remove();
    $('#database-div').append(`
        <table id="database" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="display: none;">
            <thead><tr><th>Casename</th><th>Password</th><th>Hash</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>`);
}
```